# Find all the units of the ring $R=\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R=\mathbb{R}^2$ is a commutative ring with addition $(a_1,b_1)+(a_2,b_2)=(a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2)$ and multiplication $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,a_1b_2+b_1a_2)$. Find all units of $R$.

---

We can easily check that the identity exists and is equal to $(1,0)$. Now we need to determine the values of $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,a_1b_2+b_1a_2)=(1,0)$.

We see that $a_1a_2$ needs to equal $1$ and $a_1b_2+b_1a_2$ needs to equal $0$. But how do I proceed from here? I don't believe it's sufficient to state that all values that satisfy the conditions above qualify.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** The given ring is isomorphic to $ \mathbb R[X]/(X^2) $. The only non-trivial ideal of this ring is $ (X) $. What can you say about the ideal generated by a non-unit?

Comment: This is definitely the right way to answer this question. +1

Answer (score 4):

Let $a\neq 0$. I claim that $(a,b)$ is a unit (for arbitrary $b$). You can indeed check that $(a,b)\cdot( \frac1{a}, -\frac{b}{a^2}) = (1,\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b}{a}) = (1,0)$, so that $(a,b)$ is invertible.

You already noticed that to be a unit, you need to have some $a'$ such that $a\cdot a'=1$, which implies that $a\neq 0$. So the set of units is precisely the set of elements of the form $\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2 : a\neq 0\}$.